# Custom hook stuck in recursive loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Trying to follow the example from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html), I encounter an endless loop when updating state in my function. Code as below:

`Home.jsx:`

```
...
import { studentDefaults } from "./student";
import { getStudent } from "./api";

function useStudent() {
  const [student, setStudent] = useState(studentDefaults);

  function handleStudentChange(student) {
    setStudent(student);
  }

  // Fetch the student after mount
  useEffect(() => {
    getStudent(handleStudentChange);
  });
  return student;
}

function StudentForm(props) {
  // Use the student here
  const student = useStudent();
  return ( <MyComponent student={student} /> )
}
```

`api.js:`

```
import request from "request-promise";
import { auth } from "./firebase/firebase";

const url =
  "http://localhost:5000/projectID/region/api";

export const getStudent = async handleStudentChange => {
  try {
    const token = await auth.currentUser.getIdToken(false);
    const student = await request(url + `?token=${token}`);
    handleStudentChange(student);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};
```

This all fetches and sets correctly, but it goes into a recursive loop, and I cant figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `useEffect` inside `useStudent` will be run every time `useStudent` is run. Since you are updating the state in the function given to it, it will loop indefinitely.

By giving an empty array as the second argument to `useEffect` you make it so that it is only run once after the initial render.

```js
function useStudent() {
  const [student, setStudent] = useState(studentDefaults);

  function handleStudentChange(student) {
    setStudent(student);
  }

  // Fetch the student after mount
  useEffect(() => {
    getStudent(handleStudentChange);
  }, []);

  return student;
}
```